# Filter for one date from DateTimeTZRange

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model which returns the date range in below mentioned way i need to check if today is 10 days before the days as you can see in the below returned date if today date + 10 days = start_end_range

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    start_end_range = ranges.DateTimeTZRange()


'start_end_range': DateTimeTZRange(datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 30, 20, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 30, 20, 30),
```

Comment: A single date is not going to equal a timestamp range. It will either be contained in the range or not. Also you seem to mixing dates and timestamps(datetimes). **To your question add a more detailed description of what you want to achievw?**

Comment: @AdrianKlaver So in website i have a date field when i select the date for from and to date(range) it actually selects the same date in start and end but the time varies as mentioned in **start_end_range** so i want to filter the data by checking if today is 10 days or certain number of days before **start_end_range**

Comment: 1) You are not working with  a `date` field you are working with a `datetime`/`timestamp` field as you have a `time` component.  2) Why have `datetime`/`timestamp`  when you are comparing `date`s? **Per previous request add this information as update to question, not in the comments**.

Answer (score 0):

A first draft of a solution. This is based on some assumptions, namely that you want the date check to be `==`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
from psycopg2.extras import DateTimeTZRange

dtr = DateTimeTZRange('2022-08-08 06:00', '2022-08-08 8:30') 

d = dtr.lower
d                                                                                                                                                            
'2022-08-08 06:00'

start_date = datetime.fromisoformat(d)                                                                                                                                      
start_date
datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 8, 6, 0)

test_dt = datetime(2022, 7, 25)
(test_dt + timedelta(days=10)) ==  start_dt
False
```